# How to limit the number of page links in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-pagination

I have **500+** records in `Users` table and I am showing list using following code in my Blade template.

In Controller

```
$users= Users::paginate(5);
```

In Blade view

```
$users->links();
```

This is showing pages from 1 to 10,
But I want to display first and last two pages from `1, 2 ....... 9,10`,

If user on page 5 pages should display like  `3,4 ... 5... 9,10`

Comment: This might answer your question: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#adjusting-the-pagination-link-window

Comment: Have you read this ? https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination#customizing-the-pagination-view, you can publish the vendor and customize it by yourself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the onEachSide() method

```php
{{ $users->onEachSide(2)->links() }}
```

Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#adjusting-the-pagination-link-window